# How to edit only the Firstname (givenName) of multiple users and import with csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-from-excel

If I have a list of users where the samAccountName for all the users are all numerical Example, 745744, 745746, etc…. I was looking for a powershell script that could accomplish the following:

1. Put an “XX” without quotes in front of the users first name/givenname
2. Have the script import the list of users from the csv file if I have a list of all the users samAccountName.

Is having only one column in excel with the samAccountName sufficient for the csv, or do i need to also have all of the users givenName as well inside of the csv?? Example column A samAccountName, column B Firstname??

Example givenName is, JOAQUIN, I would need the first name to be XXJOAQUIN. I have about 500 users that I would have to do this for, and we are doing it manually right now, So the only thing that I need changed is adding the “XX” before the users givenNames….

Thanks everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your CSV file just contains a header with the `samAccountName` followed by the samAccountNames like this:

> samAccountName
>    745744
>    745746

Then you can use the following piece of code, change the path to the path of the csv file with your users.
This could be made shorter and use the pipeline better to make it less code, but this will work just fine.

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\users.csv 

foreach($user in $users) {
$obj = Get-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.samAccountName -GivenName ("xx" + $obj.GivenName)
}
```

Comment: hey henrik and hal9256. thanks for the super quick response. You guys are AWESOME. All of the samAccount names are numerical (they are all student accounts). Im going to test the script out in a few minutes on a test user to see what it does. i will reply back shortly..  Question if the path to the csv was c:\users.csv do i edit the script to look like this $users = Import-Csv -Path c:\users.csv ? do i have to enclose quotes around the path?? sorry im not smart lol

Comment: OK i ran the script and it works perfect. Last question if it was you and you had 500 users to do would u do all of them at one time or would you split it up in batches?

Comment: You could do all of them at the same time, no problem. Since it gets each user by samAccountName it doesn't really matter which OU they are in. The only reason to do it in batches would be if it makes sense to you, like if you need to inform the users or there are other processes in your end where you need to do something. If not, go nuts and do it in a single go, that is after all the awesome power of the shell :)

Comment: sooo Amazing u are!!!! Henrik you should take a peek at the script below from Paxz when i ran his script on a test user just now it replaced the entire givenname with only xx. I wonder what he did wrong??

Comment: Good morning henrik i wanted to ask a new question, and was hoping you could help me. Same scenario -- have list of users (about 200 samAccountName's) and the only field that needs to be updated in AD is the telephoneNumber field. Example user John Smith Telephone number is 44444 and needs to be changed to 12345. Im guessing the csv file would contain column for samAccountName and the 2nd column would be telephoneNumber which would be a list of the numbers that are going to overwrite whatever the users current number is in AD.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a CSV with samAccountName as the first column, you can do something like this.

```
$Users = Import-CSV "Users.csv"
Foreach($User in $Users){

$ADUser = Get-ADUser $User.samAccountName

$ADUser.GivenName = "XX$($ADUser.GivenName)"

Set-ADUser -Instance $ADUser
}
```

If you are searching for numerical users, you can look up in the documentation to use `Get-ADUser` to get all your users, and use a `foreach` loop to evaluate if it is numerical, and set the account.

Comment: is it not redundant to pipe your $Users  variable into a foreach? You could remove the `$Users |` and get the same result :)

Comment: Oh yeah, (edited), I usually pipe things into a `Foreach-Object` but decided to use a traditional `foreach` statement to make things clearer to understand, and forgot to remove the pipe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pipe the output directly from `Get-ADUser` to `Set-ADUser` like this:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\users.csv 
foreach($user in $users) {
  Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName | % {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -GivenName ("xx" + $_.GivenName)}
}
```

Another way would be:

```
$users = Import-Csv -Path .\users.csv 
foreach($user in $users) {
  Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName -GivenName ("xx" + $(Get-ADuser -Identity $user.SamAccountName).GivenName)
}
```

Comment: this one didnt work It totally replaced the givenname with only xx. Henrik Stanley worked as intended!!

Comment: @Paxz I think that the issue is that the $_. doesn't work since the object from the Get-ADUser is for some reason not in the pipeline. I am not sure why, I tested this myself first, couldn't get it to work and decided to go with getting the ad user in a variable first. I think if we run the command with a -verbose it should be possible to see what gets passed in the pipe.

Comment: @HenrikStanleyMortensen Well using foreach like in the edit fixes it. (not the optimal soluton)

Comment: I agree that it is much neater passing the object through the pipeline and referencing the object. Why it is not working I am not sure, would require some digging to see what gets passed through the pipeline.

Comment: ok Pax your 1st one works now Get-ADUser -Identity $user.SamAccountName | %....... but the 2nd one will still replace givenname with only xx. You and @HenrikStanley.... both did great!!!!!

Comment: @jwalk_pv2001 yeah i did a typo there, try it now.

Comment: @Pax 2nd one still a no go.... still overwrite everything and replace only with xx

Comment: that's because the `$user` is coming from the imported csv file. `$user.GivenName` is therefore nothing unless there is a column in the csv called 'GivenName'. The 1st actually first gets the AD user using the SamAccountname in the csv. There the `$_.GivenName` is a property of that user object and has meaning.