# How to change multiple telephone numbers in AD from a CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-from-excel

Good Morning Everyone,

I have a list of users (about 200 samAccountName's) and the only field that needs to be updated in AD is the telephoneNumber field. Example user John Smith Telephone number is 44444 and needs to be changed to 12345. Im guessing the csv file would contain a column for samAccountName, and the 2nd column would be telephoneNumber which would be a list of the numbers that are going to overwrite whatever the users current number is in AD.

i was thinking i could use the script from @Henrik Stanley Mortensen and modify it, but not sure what fields to change. THis is the url from my 1st question....

[How to edit only the Firstname (givenName) of multiple users and import with csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544903/how-to-edit-only-the-firstname-givenname-of-multiple-users-and-import-with-csv)

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. The script you mention is a very good startingpoint.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What you are asking is a very simple task both in terms of PowerShell scripting and Active Directory management. If you find yourself unable to come up with at least a first shot at the problem I strongly recommend you read up on both matters involved or hire someone to do your work for you.

Comment: dont be mean people. if i knew how to do it i would not ask the question. I can do it manually though it's not a big deal. i was just curious if it could be automated. Im going to try to learn powershell over the christmas holiday but was hoping someone here could help with this question.

Comment: So far, i have tried to modify this Import-Csv .csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{Mobile=$_.MobilePhone}} to this Import-Csv c:\Adobe\users.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{"Telephone number"=$_.telephoneNumber}} but got error

Comment: I was able to get it to work i tried this Import-Csv c:\Adobe\users.csv | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samAccountName -Replace @{telephoneNumber=$_.telephoneNumber}} and it worked.....

Comment: Please add your code to the question, do not place it in the comments.

Comment: whoops well you found it while I was typing my answer. Would still recommend that -whatif when playing with AD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me say I agree stack is not a code generation site. It goes a long way if you have a little bit of code to show as to what you have tried. Even if it is TERRIBLE others in the community will feel compassion and empathy towards you versus negativity. Second please go to amazon and buy the book "Learn Powershell in a Month of Lunches" This will help you a ton and get your fundamentals down. Real easy read.

[https://www.amazon.com/Learn-Windows-PowerShell-Month-Lunches/dp/1617294160/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1533311287&sr=8-3&keywords=powershell+books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617294160)

Ok now off my soapbox. So I have created a csv called updatetelphones.csv and placed it in my C:\temp folder on my desktop. It has two columns one called SamAccountName and a second Called TelephoneNumber. Notice no spaces. With powershell we want to import that into a variable then iterate through each item and set the phone number for the user.

```
$UsersToUpdate = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\updatetelephones.csv"

foreach($User in $UsersToUpdate)
{
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User.SamAccountName -OfficePhone $User.TelephoneNumber -WhatIf    
}
```

Above is the powershell code. Now look carefully at the end of my set-aduser command I have a -whatif. ANYTIME you are making changes to AD I recommend you test your script with the -whatif first. That simulates the changes but doesn't make any so you can confirm it is accurate. So use this to test on your side. Once you validate remove the "-whatif" and run to actually make the changes. Peace and Happy powershell learning!!

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to the post i really appreciate it, and will definitely purchase the book you mentioned to read during the christmas holiday. I'm go to re-read your answer right now and see if i understand everything....

Comment: Sounds good man!! PS I am not affiliated with that book by any means. I have all my sysadmins read that I hire and helps a lot.

Comment: Hey JMill i just tested your script, and it works too. Thank you again!!

Comment: @jwalk_pv2001 also not sure if you are using the powershell command prompt or ise but if you are not using ise use that to create your powershell scripts. ISE is already installed on your computer and is much more friendly.

Comment: wzup @JMill yeah i was using ISE to test the script and then run the script question when u said the -Whatif statement is used to simulate the script does this mean that after i run the script and then it takes me back to the prompt with no errors that means the script is good and then i can remove the -Whatif statement??

Comment: the "-whatif" will show you in output what it was going to do. In this case you will see a message stating performing the operation "Set" on target etc for each item you are making a change. Depending on commands you get different output and it is good to use that just to make sure it is only changing items you expect it to. But yeah you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

it is strange, I use telephonenumber as a Get-ADUser property but OfficePhone as a parameter to set the telephonenumber property

```
Set-AdUser -Identity $user.SID -Credential $credential -OfficePhone $vp_telephonenumber -Server DC2.abc.com
```